# sum group by in MDX

Tags: mdx

I want the equivalent SUM and Group By as in t-SQL. But I haven't found the answer on the web. 
My MDX return has some records that have the same name. I want to show the distinct name with the measure summed up just like Group by feature in SQL.

It seems like it's a common feature. Thanks.

Comment: It seems from what I have seen online that `GROUP BY` isn't really necessary, the language constructs allow equivalent operations without explicit mention.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a measure in AS you can set it several different ways including count and sum.

Let's assume you have a product dimension and a fact of sales.  A simple query to get the total sales by product would look like the following.

```
SELECT {[Measures].[ItemCount], [Measures].[SalesDollars]} ON 0,
[Products].[Products].children ON 1
FROM [CUBE]
```

This would give you sample output like

```
Product  Item Count     Sales Dollars
Bike     10             1000
Tire      3              650
```